# Replacing more than one whitespace within a textfile (VBS)

Tags: vbscript, whitespace

I have a problem with a simlar textfile by replacing chars, who are very often in the file (multiple appearence), especially whitespaces.
When I use this script

```
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

soll1 = " "
soll2 = "<i>"
soll3 = "<b>"
ist1  = "  "  ' replacing two spaces by one space
ist2  = "//"
ist3  = "**"

Set readFile  = fso.OpenTextFile("Eingabe.txt",1,false)
set writefile = fso.CreateTextFile("Ausgabe.txt",2)

' Do until readfile.AtEndOfStream
' Do while not readfile.AtEndOfStream
  While not readfile.AtEndOfStream
    ThisLine = readfile.ReadLine
    If Instr(Soll1,ThisLine) Then   
    writefile.write Replace(ThisLine,ist2,soll2)
    writefile.write Replace(ThisLine,ist3,soll3)
    writefile.write Replace(ThisLine,"  "," ")  ' ist1/soll1
    Else
    writefile.write ThisLine & vbCrLf
    End If
Wend
' Loop

readfile.close
writefile.close
```

I could see no efforts in the generated file called "Ausgabe.txt", no doubled or tripled whitespace has being replaced. What I'm doing wrong?
I also also tried *Do until ...* and *Do while not ...*
What is wrong ? Please help, thanks, bedankt Uw

Comment: Are they spaces or are they other whitespace characters would be the first thing I check.

Comment: They are all Whitespace Characters (Hex 020), // and ** are also not changed

Comment: The `CreateTextFile()` takes a boolean for its second argument - See the [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/5t9b5c0c(v=vs.84)).

Comment: The script has several syntax and logic errors. As noted, the argument for `CreateTextFile` is incorrect (it would be correct if `OpenTextFile` were used). The arguments for `Instr(Soll1,ThisLine)` are transposed. The variable `ThisLine` needs to be updated for each search and replace pair and with just a single `WriteLine` of `ThisLine` for each iteration of `ReadLine`.

Comment: I changed the "2" as a Boolean to True, but it still won't work ?!

Comment: You have much more to fix. See my previous comment.

Comment: See this [example](https://github.com/LesFerch/SampleCode/blob/main/VBS-misc/SearchReplace.vbs) for an in memory search and replace and see this [example](https://github.com/LesFerch/SampleCode/blob/main/VBS-misc/SearchReplaceLargeFile.vbs) for a line by line search and replace (only needed for very large files).

Comment: @LesFerch, thanks for the examples. I tried some, but those Array-Things work only for 50 per cent. Some whitespaces aren't changed. So I started again changing those whitespaces with ' and made the following script, which works:

Comment: @LesFerch,thanks for the script examples. I tried some of them, but those Array-Things work only for 50 per cent. Some whitespaces aren't changed. So I started again changing those whitespaces in the input file with # (for better viewing) and made the following piece of script, which works:
```
...
aSearch = Array("######","#####","####","###","##","//","**") 'abscending number
aReplace = Array("#","#","#","#","#","<i>","<b>")
...
```
With Your file: SearchReplace.vbs.
Why does the old iteration fails ?

Comment: My example replaces all occurrences of a double space with a single space (one pass). If you have three or more spaces in a row, you should introduce an additional loop to replace double spaces until they are all gone. I'll update the examples accordingly.

Comment: See the updated examples.

Comment: Hi, Dear, thanks for the updates. Your Loop does bring the needed iteraton. Good work, carry on !

Answer (score 0):

To reduce all strings of a given character (such as space) to a single character, you can repeat the search and replace until no more occurrences are found. Here's an example:

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
InFile = "Eingabe.txt"
OutFile = "Ausgabe.txt"

aSearch = Array("  ","//","**")
aReplace = Array(" ","<i>","<b>")

Contents = oFSO.OpenTextFile(InFile).ReadAll

For i = 0 To UBound(aSearch)
  Do While Instr(Contents,aSearch(i))>0
    Contents = Replace(Contents,aSearch(i),aReplace(i))
  Loop
Next

oFSO.CreateTextFile(OutFile,True).Write(Contents)
```

Here's a variation that processes one line at a time (useful for very large files):

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
InFile = "Eingabe.txt"
OutFile = "Ausgabe.txt"

aSearch = Array("  ","//","**")
aReplace = Array(" ","<i>","<b>")

Set oInFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(InFile)
Set oOutFile = oFSO.CreateTextFile(OutFile,True)

Do While Not oInFile.AtEndOfStream
  Line = oInFile.ReadLine
  For i = 0 To UBound(aSearch)
    Do While Instr(Line,aSearch(i))>0
      Line = Replace(Line,aSearch(i),aReplace(i))
    Loop
  Next
  oOutFile.WriteLine Line
Loop

oInFile.Close
oOutFile.Close
```